# Export phonebook contacts to excel

Tags: android, export-to-excel

I have a list view that shows my phonebook contacts, now i want to export these contacts to an excel file?
How can i achieve this in my application?

Please help. any example or tutorial would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just write the comments out as a CSV file. An other example would be to use the Excel XML format. Or use a library like Apachi POI.

Comment: Export phonebook contacts as a CSV file